# converting Json coordinate into CLLocationCoordinate2D

Tags: objective-c, json, postgis

I have a service returning geographies (points and polygons) the object return as strings for example:

"POINT (51.38494009999999 -0.3514684)"

I can do string manipulations to extract the two values but was wondering if there is a better way to convert that into CLLocationCoordinate2D.

mainly because of the polygons, inserting point by point doesn't seem like the correct solution.

Comment: you can try using NSRegularExpression, which might be faster that simple string manipulations, but as for translating JSON string into a C struct, i don't think that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more appropriate structure to represent a polygon, you could use the `MKPolygon` class from MapKit. It accepts an array of CLLocationCoordinate2D points as it's initialiser. Using this class may be handy if you are planning to interact with MapKit in your application. Otherwise, it is probably unnecessary to do so - a custom class will likely be the desired container then.

Comment: I'm working with google maps and they have a GSMPolygon which is basically the same as MKPolygon, what I'm trying to solve is not loading the CLLocationCoordinate2D into the polygon but loading the polygon with a string like this POLYGON((0 0, 10 10, 10 0, 0 0)) with coordinates instead of numbers

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing [well-known text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text), which was produced by [ST_AsText](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_AsText.html). If you actually were expecting JSON and you are able to modify the server-side query, use [ST_AsGeoJSON](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_AsGeoJSON.html) to instead return:

```
{"type":"Point","coordinates":[51.3849401,-0.3514684]}
```

If you have only point data, also consider returning the double precision data, [ST_X](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_X.html) for longitude and [ST_Y](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Y.html) for latitude. The last suggestion of course does not require any parsing of text results, but does not work on linestrings or polygons.